# Modify the structure of a json

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am trying to modify the following text in json. The following chain the following structure:

```
  {
  "cabecera": {
    "tipo_cambio": "",
    "fecha_emision": "",
    "total": ""
  },
  "detalle": {
    "940b130369614bd6b687dc5b41623439": {
      "producto": "94115891",
      "detalle_adicional": "",
      "cantidad": "",
      "precio_unitario": "",
      "subtotal": "",
      "total": ""
    },
    "6cbdcef2bbff4b059c8de7432c9aa5f2": {
      "producto": "6738756",
      "detalle_adicional": "",
      "cantidad": "",
      "precio_unitario": "",
      "subtotal": "",
      "total": ""
    }
  }
}
```

And I would like to modify it to the following structure so that the codes like "940b130369614bd6b687dc5b41623439" disapear and dtalle becomes and array.

```
{
  "cabecera": {
    "tipo_cambio": "",
    "fecha_emision": "",
    "total": ""
  },
  "detalle": [
    {
      "producto": "94115891",
      "detalle_adicional": "",
      "cantidad": "",
      "precio_unitario": "",
      "subtotal": "",
      "total": ""
    },
    {
      "producto": "6738756",
      "detalle_adicional": "",
      "cantidad": "",
      "precio_unitario": "",
      "subtotal": "",
      "total": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**Is there any way to do it in C#?**

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself yet? Do you know which language you want to do it in?

Comment: Try it with dynamic type, JArray.Parse in .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small C# program that solves the problem

```
string origJson =
@"{
""cabecera"": {
    ""tipo_cambio"": """",
    ""fecha_emision"": """",
    ""total"": """"
},
""detalle"": {
    ""940b130369614bd6b687dc5b41623439"": {
    ""producto"": ""94115891"",
    ""detalle_adicional"": """",
    ""cantidad"": """",
    ""precio_unitario"": """",
    ""subtotal"": """",
    ""total"": """"
    },
    ""6cbdcef2bbff4b059c8de7432c9aa5f2"": {
        ""producto"": ""6738756"",
        ""detalle_adicional"": """",
        ""cantidad"": """",
        ""precio_unitario"": """",
        ""subtotal"": """",
        ""total"": """"
    }
}
}";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(origJson);
JArray detalleChilds = new JArray(obj.SelectToken("detalle").Select(x => x.Children()));

obj.Remove("detalle");
obj.Add("detalle", detalleChilds);

Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

In order to use this example you need to install the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much